# ngnix on amazon ec2 instance which has RedHat 4.4.4-13?

Tags: redhat, amazon-ec2, django

I have an ec2 instance running on amazon which has AMI(ami-1b814f72).Its running  RedHat 4.4.4-13 version.

I want to install ngnix and gunicorn on with django. According to ngnix http://wiki.nginx.org/Install#Official_Red_Hat.2FCentOS_packages page I need to create a file `/etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo` and paste those line for finding repo.But they also mentioned that :

> Due to differences between how CentOS, RHEL, and Scientific Linux
>   populate the $releasever variable, it is necessary to manually replace
>   $releasever with either "5" (for 5.x) or "6" (for 6.x), depending upon
>   your OS version.

But I don't have either 5 or 6 version. I have RedHat 4.4.4-13 version, so what should I do in that case to make it work and get installed ngnix on my ec2 instance.

If I dont change the baseurl and try to install ngnix I got this error:

> http://nginx.org/packages/rhel/latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
>   [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"
>   Trying other mirror. Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata
>   (repomd.xml) for repository: ngnix. Please verify its path and try
>   again

**Please note: I want to be under AWS free Usage Tier and I don't want to be get charged**

Answer (score 1):

RHEL4 is no longer supported by Red Hat (https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata/).  It's entirely possible that the Nginx guys have not created RPMs for RHEL4, so there will be no repo for it.

If you want to run nginx on RHEL4, you will need to compile it yourself.  A further recommendation would be to use a supported version of RHEL.